# add marker to geolocate button

Tags: openlayers, geolocation, markers

I'm doing a map to describe trekking paths and I need a button for the geolocation function. I saw ol examples about custom control, button and geolocation, and using the drupal geolocate button I managed to get a [map](https://jsfiddle.net/arts1983/q8a8tgsg/). It works, but I need a marker to locate the position, and I added the following code at row 86, but it doesn't work, I'm doing something wrong?

```
positionFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#3399CC'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 2
        })
    })
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the map as a parameter to your control.
Map is undefined on the way you pass it.
Change the last line of your code

from this

`map.addControl(new app.Geolocate());`

to this

`map.addControl(new app.Geolocate('',map));`

check your fiddle with this tiny change [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/j9efk0de/)

Comment: no probs. glad to help.